# Any differences in 3d interpolation between MATLAB and Numpy/Scipy?

Tags: python, matlab, multidimensional-array, interpolation

I'm a MATLAB user and I'm trying to translate some code in Python as an assignment. Since I noticed some differences between the two languages in 3d interpolation results from my original code, I am trying to address the issue by analysing a simple example.

I set a 2x2x2 matrix (named blocc below) with some values, and its coordinates in three vectors (X,Y,Z). Given a query point, I use 3D-linear interpolation to find the intepolated value. Again,I get different results in MATLAB and Python (code below).

Python

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.interpolate as si

X,Y,Z =(np.array([1, 2]),np.array([1, 2]),np.array([1, 2]))

a = np.ones((2,2,1))
b = np.ones((2,2,1))*2

blocc = np.concatenate((a,b),axis=2) # Matrix with values

blocc[1,0,0]=7
blocc[0,1,1]=7

qp = np.array([2,1.5,1.5]) #My query point

value=si.interpn((X,Y,Z),blocc,qp,'linear')

print(value)
```

Here I get value=3

MATLAB

```
blocc = zeros(2,2,2);
blocc(:,:,1) = ones(2,2);
blocc(:,:,2) = ones(2,2)*2;

blocc(2,1,1)=7;
blocc(1,2,2)=7;

X=[1,2];
Y=[1,2];
Z=[1,2];

qp = [2 1.5 1.5];

value=interp3(X,Y,Z,blocc,qp(1),qp(2),qp(3),'linear')
```

And here value=2.75

I can't understand why: I think there is something I don't get about how does interpolation and/or matrix indexing work in Python. Can you please make it clear for me? Thanks!

Comment: In MATLAB you do `value=interp3(X,Y,Z,blocc,1.5,1.5,1.5,'linear')`, don't you mean `value=interp3(X,Y,Z,blocc,qp(1),qp(2),qp(3),'linear')`? The values are different!

Comment: That's what I did, just copied the wrong line. I edited my post, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, for MATLAB when `X`, `Y` and `Z` are vectors, then it considers that the order of the dimensions in the values array is `(Y, X, Z)`. From [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html#bt2rbzl-1-V):

> **`V` — Sample values**
>   array
>
> Sample values, specified as a real or complex array. The size requirements for `V` depend on the size of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`:
>
> - If `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are arrays representing a full grid (in `meshgrid` format), then the size of `V` matches the size of `X`, `Y`, or `Z` .
> - If `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are grid vectors, then `size(V) = [length(Y) length(X) length(Z)]`.
>
> If `V` contains complex numbers, then `interp3` interpolates the real and imaginary parts separately.
>
> **Example:** `rand(10,10,10)`
>
> **Data Types:** `single | double`
>   **Complex Number Support:** Yes

This means that, to get the same result in Python, you just need to swap the first and second values in the query:

```
qp = np.array([1.5, 2, 1.5])
f = si.interpn((X, Y, Z), blocc, qp, 'linear')
print(f)
# [2.75]
```

Comment: Ok! I'll consider this also in the bigger issue I mentioned before. Thank you!